# RTF format: How to fit the cell width to RichEdit width?

Tags: width, cell, rtf, autosize

I have bellow **rtf** table:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\cellx1000 \cellx2000 \cellx3000
\intbl 
TEXT1             \cell 
TEXT2             \cell 
VERY_LONG_TEXT3   \cell
\row
}
```

I want **first cell** and **second cell** have *fix size*, and **third cel**l *auto size* to fit the **RichEdit** width.

**Example**: if RichEdit's width resize to 10,000 then cell 1 & 2 width = 1000, cell 3 width = 8000.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try using **\trautofit1** and **\clftsWidth1**, as described in the answer below, to achieve the behaviour you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531449/1997617